# React Stripe Elements not showing up?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

Hi I am new to using Stripe and Stripe Elements in React. I am using the packages react-stripe-js and stripe-js, as explained in https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react.
I have two components one calles StripeWrapper :

```
import React from 'react';

// stripe
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';

// components
import CheckoutForm from './CheckoutForm';

// stripe load
const stripePromise = loadStripe(...);

const StripeWrapper = () => {
    return (  
        <Elements stripe={ stripePromise } >
            <CheckoutForm /> 
        </Elements>
    );
};
 
export default StripeWrapper;
```

Which is only a HOC to wrap the actual CheckoutForm with the Elements component, again, as explained in Stripe documentation. And the actual form component:

```
const CheckoutForm = () => {

  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  // dispatch
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const setStep = useCallback(
    step => dispatch( setStepperAction(step) ),
    [ dispatch ],
  );

  const handleSubmitPayment = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!stripe || !elements) return;
    
    ...
  };

  return (  
      <Col xs={12} className="bg-light px-1 my-2">
        <Form inline className="mx-0 w-100 h-100"
          onSubmit={ handleSubmitPayment }
        >  
          <label>
            Número de tarjeta
            <CardNumberElement />
          </label>
          <label>
            Fecha de caducidad
            <CardExpiryElement />
          </label>
          <label>
            CVC
            <CardCvcElement />
          </label>
          <Button type="submit" disabled={ !stripe } > Pagar </Button>
        </Form>
      </Col>
  );
}
 
export default CheckoutForm;
```

But those elements are not displaying at al, only the labels and the button. What am I missing here? It is exactly reproduced as shown in Stripe docs. I could use a bit of help here, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I figure out that the Card fields disappear when we apply a `display:flex` CSS rule on the enclosing tag.

Solution that works for me : Apply `width:100%;` to the `.StripeElement` CSS class (this class come with the card field). In the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-stripe-js-card-detailed-omfb3) they did this.

Answer (score 1):

I was having that issue too. I solved the problem by putting the publishable key directly into the loadstripe function.
like this:

> const  stripePromise = loadStripe('your publishable key here')

Comment: Which approach did you use before (the one that didn't work)? The OP claims to have followed the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react) closely. There you can see this snippet `const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx'
);` which is what OP did too, I'd guess.